# ASP Wizard Step

Tags: asp.net, accessibility, wizard

I am not particularly proficient in ASP, so I might be missing something obvious here. I have a series of webpages that are using a wizardstep in asp to process. In the HTML markup that is returned there are some issues that have been brought to my attention to do with accessibility. The problem is that basically the HTML table returned is using attributes, rather than css style to display the data. I cannot see anywhere in the asp code where these attributes are being specified so I am unable to amend them. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Cheers.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<h2><span style="font-size:90%;">
Code of Conduct for Members</span></h2>
<div style="text-align: center">
<asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server"  DisplaySideBar="false" width="550px" ActiveStepIndex="0"  OnFinishButtonClick="Wizard1_FinishButtonClick">
<WizardSteps>
        <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" runat="server" Title="Step 1">
          <!-- <h2> -->
                <span style="font-size:110%;position:relative;">Introduction</span></h2>
            <p >
                <span style="font-size:90%;">
```

This is from the iframe within this webpage: http://www.leicestershire-fire.gov.uk/cfa/complaints_members.shtml

Basically I can see this on the generated page as:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="Wizard1" style="width:550px;border-collapse:collapse;">

<tr style="height:100%;">

    <td align="left" valign="top" style="background-color:White;border-color:White;border-style:Solid;">
```

Comment: The question is a little unclear, can you try adding some code or providing a little more information?

Comment: It is basically the iframe, within this page that I am having trouble with: http://www.leicestershire-fire.gov.uk/cfa/complaints_members.shtml

Comment: Please use the questions edit function to add more details to your question, code in comments are unreadable.

Comment: Have deleted my comments with code in and amended the question as requested. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using an old version of ASP.NET, which is notorious for using inline styles instead of css classes.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Upgrade to ASP.NET 4. Search this page for "wizard": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s57a598e.aspx. This is preferable, although upgrading may alter the look and feel of your other pages and components. There are ways of making it backwards-compatible (see TargetFramework)
2. Install a CSS Adapter: http://www.asp.net/CssAdapters/ - as you can see though, this hasn't been updated since 2006.

You may also find this page useful so you can see an example of what the issue is and how they solve it with CSS Adapters: http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/Membership/CreateUserWizard.aspx

Comment: I am double checking our site, but I believe you are correct. It appears to be running on ASP.NET 3.5, so I will look and see what I can do to either upgrade it or use the adapters, thanks